# Prevent GradientDrawable to redraw while animating

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I have set a GradientDrawable as background. While doing some 3d transaction (especially at the Y axis) the GradientDrawable redraws it self and the famerate is not good.

- I cannot cache the view that the drawing is set as background because
  i want other views on top of that to animate.
- I cannot put another view just for the background and cache that view
  cause then that view only beeing fullscreen will cause the same
  problems.
- I cannot use windowsDecorator for the background.

So what i want is a way to stop the GradientDrawable to try to redraw itself during the animation. I think `jumpToCurrentState()` does what i want but i want it to work on API level >= 8 and `jumpToCurrentState()` is only for API level >=11. Also i wish i knew what jumpToCurrentState does exactly to port it to the API lvl 8 but can't find the function anywhere in the drawable(source not released?)

So is there **any** way to cache the drawable it self and not the view containing that Drawable?.

The last resort will be to not draw the background during animations but i really really want to avoid that.

Comment: have you tried extending the GradientDrawable and delaying the draw with Drawable.Callback.scheduleDrawable(...), never used it myself but it might work here

Comment: well i will try that now.scheduleDrawable blocks the Drawable to render to a new state until it fires?

Comment: maybe ignore the draw and inject your own logic, set when = 0... if I understand correctly...

Comment: ok i ended up creating a cache for the drawables i will post my answer when it's finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a bitmap caching system for the GradientDrawable it self. (Didn't want to cache the view that has this drawable as a background).

This gives a great speed boost for animations.

```
  public class PGradientDrawable extends GradientDrawable {

    private int firstColor;
    private int secondColor;
    private Paint cachePaint = new Paint();
    private Canvas cacheCanvas = new Canvas();
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public PGradientDrawable(Orientation angle, int[] intarray) {
        super(angle, intarray);
        firstColor = intarray[0];
        secondColor = intarray[1];
    }

    public boolean isBackground = false;
    boolean firstTime = true;

    public void buildCache(int width, int height) {
        if (bitmap != null)
            bitmap.recycle();
        try {
            bitmap = Bitmap
                    .createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bitmap.setDensity(context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
            cacheCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
            // TODO shader must be what the GradientDrawable is,type
            // orientation..
            cachePaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height,
                    firstColor, secondColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
            cacheCanvas.drawPaint(cachePaint);

        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // clear the bitmap force draw() to repaint
            bitmap = null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            // Draw the bitmap
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
            return;
        }
        super.draw(canvas);
    }

}
```